# JQuery to loop through a variable number of items in an asp repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get `jQuery` to loop through my asp repeater, only showing a selected number of items each time.

I've been able to get it to show 1 item at a time, but I want it to show as many items as a request parameter asks for.

For example if I call the url like this, `http://somesite/page.aspx?no_of_items=2`, the `jQuery` should rotate through the repeater 2 items at a time.

here's my code so far.

```
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $divItem = $('.item');
        $divItem.hide().eq(0).show();
        var itemCnt = $divItem.length;
        setInterval(itemSlider, 3000);
        function itemSlider() {
            $divItem.eq(($divItem.length++) % itemCnt)
            .fadeOut("1600", function () {
                $divItem.eq(($divItem.length) % itemCnt)
               .fadeIn("1000");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form" runat="server">
    <div class="placeholder" style="width: 573px; height: 600px">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterClasses">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="headline">
                        <span class="lokaal">
                            <asp:Label ID="lokaal" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nrq_ClassroomIdName") %>'></asp:Label></span>&nbsp;<span class="opleiding"><asp:Label ID="opleiding" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nrq_SubcontainerIdName") %>'></asp:Label></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <span class="tijdstip">
                            <asp:Label ID="tijdstip" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nrq_StartDate") %>'></asp:Label></span>&nbsp;<span class="docent"><asp:Label ID="docent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nrq_TeacherIdName") %>'></asp:Label></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```